# Zend Framework setup

Tags: php, javascript, html, zend-framework

Hai

I want to create a project in Zend framework, but I don't know any idea about how to include this zend framework in to wamp server. 
Any one please helps me...?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not a single question accepted? No thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is ensure that the Zend/lib directory from the framework download is in your include path.

That should work just as well on WAMP as it does anywhere else.

I haven't configured an IIS server in ages...  but it's probably just as easy as a nicely crafted "ini_set('include_path",'..') in your bootstrap script.

Once you've got Zend/lib in your include path, you can include (or autoload) Zend things as needed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need a tutorial to start from scratch, I'd say.

Here are a couple of links that could interest you :

- [Survive The Deep End!](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) : a free electronic-book about ZF

  - It's still work in progress,
  - but the [Chapter 4. Installing The Zend Framework](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/installing.the.zend.framework) is finished, and gives several way to use ZF
  - Don't forget to read to other chapters too, btw ;-)
- [The official Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart)

Those might be helpful, for you to start.

And here are some other resources :

- The official [Reference Guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/) -- not quite perfect as a starting point, but contains the documentation of every classes ; you'll work with this one pretty often, I guess !
- A [couple of screencasts](http://zendframework.com/docs/screencasts) *(including one about Installing ZF)*

  - There are also [webinars](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework), and a couple [podcasts](http://devzone.zend.com/search/results?q=%27zend+framework%27+podcast)
- More advanced, there are interesting articles about [ZF on devzone](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend%20Framework)
- Of course, you can find books about ZF, too. For instance :

  - [Beginning Zend Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218258)
  - [Zend Framework in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988320)

Answer (score 0):

i used this tutorial when i started to work with zf:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-zend1/

It's from 2006 but you should get the clue.

Have fun!